# How to properly list quotes in a sentence

Tags: punctuation, quotes, lists, quotations, quotation-marks

For a marketing class, I am listing three different slogans a company has. I have rewritten this a few times and I can't seem to get it to look correct.

My question is should I make it one big quote and place semicolons/ commas in between each quote?

The sentence I have currently is:

> Three slogans are: "Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together", "Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook", and "Bringing the world closer together".

Comment: Use bullet points.

Comment: @WeatherVane even if it is in paragraph form?

Comment: It is marketing, not prose.

Comment: Why do you think what you have is not correct?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't really know. It looks strange to me having only the commas outside the quotations.

Comment: If you follow orthodox English punctuation style, you need to place the commas before the terminating quotation marks. However, I would agree with @WeatherVane that bullet points are most natural here, unless you are forced to use prose.

Comment: This Q is better asked on [writers.se]

Comment: What you have is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you seemed to be indicating that for your particular project you need to keep everything in one paragraph, rather than going to bullets.

I assume you're in the US, since you used double quotes, rather than single.

I know three ways of doing this.

As you had it, but with the commas and the period inside the quotes:

> Three slogans are: "Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together," "Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook," and "Bringing the world closer together."

Similar to the above, but with semicolons:

> Three slogans are: "Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together;" "Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook;" and "Bringing the world closer together."

With italics instead of quotation marks:

> Three slogans are: *Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together, Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook,* and *Bringing the world closer together.*

Sometimes when things don't look aesthetically pleasing it can help to tweak the font, font size or line spacing a bit until it looks better.

Your questions:

> My question is should I make it one big quote and place semicolons/ commas in between each quote?

No.

> It looks strange to me having only the commas outside the quotations.

Look at how quotation marks and commas and periods are handled in some of your textbooks and you'll see that that's the norm.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting each slogan on a separate line of a block quote, thereby allowing you to remove the quotation marks. (Alternatively, use bullet points—also without quotation marks.)

The X company has three slogans:

> Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together.
>   Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook.
>   Bringing the world closer together.

(I can't help but notice the lack of parallelism. The third slogan has a different verb tense than the other two. Somebody should have pointed out the inconsistency. Also, I suspect the first slogan should use *a community* or *communities*.)

If a vertical presentation is not allowed, then you either have to put the commas inside the quotation marks—or keep them outside but switch to single quotation marks. (That style of punctuation is allowed in scientific texts and literary criticism where literalism is required.)

Alternatively, and probably best, remove the quotation marks altogether and put each slogan—but not the commas—in italics.

Comment: I don't think regular and italic commas are visually distinct enough to function as separators like that.

Comment: @steve First, you always leave punctuation in roman unless it is part of the text being styled (CMOS 6.2). Second, it's common to italicize words as words (or phrases as phrases) rather than to put them in quotation marks (CMOS 7.48–69, and 7.63 specifically). As none of these slogans contain commas themselves, semicolons do not need to be used; and with italics, periods can be used at the end of each to further separate them.

Comment: My point isn't to argue that this is an *improper* practice, but rather that it's not going to be visually distinct.

Comment: I don't see the lack of parallelism as a problem here, since all we're doing is quoting some slogans.  All the slogans are supposed to have in common is that they are from the PR world and they are presumably written about the same company or product. // Maybe your bit of discomfort about the lack of parallelism is an indication that paragraph form would actually be preferable.  Just a thought.

Comment: @aparente001 If they are from the same company and about the same product, then, as an easily communicated idea, parallelism is important. If they are essentially "random," and just being listed as a collection of individual examples, then parallelism isn't a concern. (The presentation has nothing to do with the grammar. *I like running, swimming, and to eat.* would be similarly awkward; it should be rephrased as *I like running, swimming, and eating.* Or *I like to run, swim, and eat.*)

Comment: @JasonBassford - I understand parallelism and I'm as picky as they come in bringing bullet points into line.  This text here, though, seems to be exactly what you said: a collection of individual slogans. I was just providing feedback for one aspect of your answer.  Apologies if it came out nitpicky....

Comment: @aparente001 Oh, I appreciate the feedback! I had assumed the slogans weren't random because of the way the question had been phrased: *I am listing three different slogans a company has.* But without further context, it's not possible to tell how they are actually being used and all we can do is speculate.

Comment: What about writing it as //Three slogans are  1) Give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together, 2) Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook, and 3) Bringing the world closer together//?  It also clears a possible doubt regarding the order it should be in.